# Jquery onmouseover() function on dynamic html images and span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some images and some span text on my page. Each image has his text and those elements are added dynamicaly with javascript.

Now, I would like to show the right message when mouseover on an image is detected.

It is not easy to explain, so here is the example:

```
var len = article_affiliations.length;
for (var affiliation_id = 0; affiliation_id < len; affiliation_id++)
{
    $('#country_warning' + affiliation_id).mouseover(function () {
        document.getElementById('country_warning_message' + affiliation_id)
            .style.visibility = 'visible';
    }).mouseout(function () {
        document.getElementById('country_warning_message' + affiliation_id)
            .style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }); 
}
```

The problem is that when the onmouseover function will be called, the affiliation_id will have the maximum value and the message will be shown near the last image, and not near the clicked one.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You might want to read up on JavaScript closures

Comment: Hi Ana, as Musa mentions you need to work with closures in your for-loop. There's a great SO post explaining your problem and the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure should do the trick:

```
for(var affiliation_id=0; affiliation_id<article_affiliations.length; affiliation_id++) {
    (function(i){
         $('#country_warning'+i).mouseover(function() {
              $('#country_warning_message'+i).css('visibility','visible');
         }).mouseout(function(){
              $('#country_warning_message'+i).css('visibility','hidden');
         });
    })(affiliation_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind your for loop in a closure for this to work. This way, all indices of `#country_warning_i` will be affected.

```
$(function () {
    $.each(article_affiliations, function (i, v) {
        $('#country_warning' + i).mouseover(function (affiliation_id, affiliation_iddddd) {
            $('country_warning_message' + i).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }).mouseout(function (i, affiliation_iddddd) {
            $('country_warning_message' + i).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        });
    });
});
```

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it with a loop that will just go through everyone of your elements. The best way of doing something like this is using the 'event.target'(built in jQuery) and 'this' objects.

Instead attach a mouseover event handler to the parent of your . The best is if your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="item">
 <img src="someimage.jpg" />
 <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <img src="someimage.jpg" />
 <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <img src="someimage.jpg" />
 <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

That way you can use a script similar to this one:

```
$('.item').on('mouseover', function() {
 $(this).find('span').show();
});
```

This will search for a span (every span) inside the element you attached the mouseover event to (for this ex the ).

Another way is to use simple css like this:

```
span {
 visibility: hidden;
}
item:hover span {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

This is an extremely simple solution and works beautifully, but unfortunately IE6 doesn't support hover on elements different from .